# Send HTTP Request API (POST) success in Post-man but it always failed in Jmeter

Tags: api, jmeter

I Do call API successful in Post-man but it always failed in Jmeter although i has added parameter or send body data
url: http://fram-mumbai.habbitzz.com/rest/all/V2/mobilewebservice/catalog/products
body data:
{"language":"en", "subCategoryId":"1215", "sortField":"name", "sortOrder":"ASC", "limit":"120", "currentPage":"1"}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGD6p.png)

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you send identical requests you should be receiving identical responses so I would recommend comparing requests which are being sent by JMeter and Postman using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and amend JMeter configuration so request would 100% match the request coming from Postman.

The most common error is missing [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header (or having an incorrect value instead of `application/json`). The header can be added using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)